# Firebase Cloud Messaging token in react native without third party libraries

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I want to implement notifications via `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

I'm using react-native (not expo) (android) and I want to know how I can get the token in the console. I've done the instructions as said in the Firebase website and was researching how I can get it.

I do not want to use third-party libraries. Is it possible?

Comment: are you using react-native-firebase library?

Comment: No. I'm not using any third party libraries. And i do not want to.

Comment: without that you cant use firebase , thats the most trusted dependency, what you can do is if you want you dont want to use any library, create a native module , and then integrate it with rn. but i would suggest ract native irebase is the best

Comment: Okay. Thank you. :)

Comment: so what areyou gonna follow? can help you

Comment: I'm gonna use the react-native-firebase library.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using react-native-firebase library. You can request for firebase token after requesting permissions for notification.

```
export const getFCMToken  = async () => {    
  const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
  let token = '';
  if (enabled) {
    token = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    AsyncStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.fcmToken, token);
  } else {
    try {
      await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      // User has authorised
      token = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
      AsyncStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.fcmToken, token);
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log('Firebase permission rejected', error);
    }
  }
};
```